# Assign string value to property in pointer to struct

Tags: c++

I have a struct (supposed to be used as binary tree leaf):

```
struct node
{
    string key;
    long value;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};
```

I'd like to initalize new object of type "node" and set its properties.

```
void insert(string key, struct node **leaf)
{
    if( *leaf == 0 )
    {
        *leaf = (struct node*) malloc( sizeof( struct node ));
        (*leaf)->value = 1;
        (*leaf)->key = key; // crash here
        (*leaf)->left = 0;    
        (*leaf)->right = 0;  
    }
    (........)
}
```

Setting value for "long value" went fine, but when trying to set "string key" my program crashes and I get "access violation".

Why and how to fix it?

Comment: Use `*leaf = new node ();` to get this working properly!

Comment: A string is a container object and not a POD structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `operator new` instead of using C function `malloc` that to allocate a new object of the type node. In this case the compiler will call the defalut constructor for data member key of type `std::string`. Otherwise data member key will not be built

For example

```
*leaf = new node { key, 1, 0, 0 };
```

or

```
*leaf = new node();
( *leaf )->key = key;
( *leaf )->value = 1;
```

data members left and right will be initialized with zero by the new operator.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` does not initialize types. This means it does not run constructors. `string` is a class type that has a constructor. So in your code the `key` member is in an invalid state. Consequently, trying to use it will cause problems.

You should almost never use `malloc` in a C++ program. Use `new` instead. `new` was designed to work with class types and call their constructors. Just remember that deallocation then has to be done via `delete` instead of `free`.